# Run a new shell process for django runserver command on AWS CodeDeploy

Tags: python, django, bash, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I have an AWS CodeDeploy script for bootstrapping/running a Django instance. However I reach a problem in that the `python manage.py runserver` command consumes the current shell process, so the CodeDeploy script never technically completes.

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

How would one run this command in a way that doesn't block the shell script? I have tried appending the command with an `&` to no avail .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using screen :

```
screen -d -m python manage.py runserver
```